# What is the correct way of parenthesizing while chaining multiple CompletableFutures?

Tags: java, asynchronous, completable-future

Let's say I have two instances of classes `Foo` and `Bar` with same name which have methods `foo` and `bar` respectively. Let's assume foo's return type is `CF<Integer>` and bar's return type is `CF<String>`. Now, what is the difference between these two ways of chaining them?

And let's assume `previousFuture` is the result from the previous computation.

#### First

```
CompletableFuture<String> result = previousFuture.thenCompose(r -> Foo.foo()).thenCompose(someInteger -> Bar.bar);
```

#### Second

```
CompletableFuture<String> result = previousFuture.thenCompose(r -> Foo.foo().thenCompose(someInteger -> Bar.bar));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both will produce the same result and will complete at an equivalent moment.

The main difference is that the first solution relies on a single call chain, which also gives you an easier access to the intermediate result if desired:

```
CompletableFuture<Integer> interm = previousFuture.thenCompose(r -> foo.foo());
CompletableFuture<String> result = interm.thenCompose(someInteger -> bar.bar());
```

The rest is probably just a matter of style preferences. For instance, if you format it on multiple lines:

```
CompletableFuture<String> result = previousFuture
        .thenCompose(r -> Foo.foo())
        .thenCompose(someInteger -> Bar.bar);
```

is probably more readable and usual than:

```
CompletableFuture<String> result = previousFuture
        .thenCompose(
            r -> foo.foo().thenCompose(someInteger -> bar.bar())
        );
```

The first solution shows better your actual data flow – a bit like when using the `Stream` API, or reactive programming.